# Haskell: Finding the source of incomplete record construction

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghc, ghci

I'm trying to debug a large, complicated program in Haskell, which I didn't entirely write myself.

I'm trying to print my data structures to diagnose a bug, but when I do so, I get the following error: `error: Prelude.undefined`. As you can see, this error is extremely non-informative.

I'm reasonably sure that this is coming from a record that I've "partially" initialized, where I'm trying to access a field whose value has not been set.

The program (a compiler) is spread over two cabal projects, a library, and an executable which uses that library. This makes debugging using GHCI/cabal-repl hard: I can't run use GHCi on the executable, because it's not the source of the error, but recreating the input the executable gives to the library is too complicated to do by hand.

I'm wondering: what can I do to get more information about where the incorrect record is being created, what field is the source of the error, etc. Is there an RTS option or something I can use to give more information for error output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiling with -Wall (or -Werror) is a good first start to finding the source of an uninitialized field. However, it might not be the source of the error. Missing record field initializions have a specific error message:

```
Prelude> data A = A { a :: Int } deriving Show
Prelude> A {}
A {a = *** Exception: <interactive>:11:1-4: Missing field in record construction a
```

If you add a strictness annotation to a record field, an error will be thrown at compile time:

```
Prelude> data A = A { a :: !Int } deriving Show
Prelude> let a = A { }

<interactive>:26:9:
    Constructor ‘A’ does not have the required strict field(s): a
    In the expression: A {}
    In an equation for ‘a’: a = A {}
```

Another option for finding the source of the error is to compile with profiling enabled and pass the -xc RTS flag.

From the GHC Users Guide:
https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html

> -xc (Only available when the program is compiled for profiling.) When an exception is raised in the program, this option causes a stack
>   trace to be dumped to stderr.
>
> This can be particularly useful for debugging: if your program is
>   complaining about a head [] error and you haven't got a clue which bit
>   of code is causing it, compiling with -prof -fprof-auto and running
>   with +RTS -xc -RTS will tell you exactly the call stack at the point
>   the error was raised.
>
> The output contains one report for each exception raised in the
>   program (the program might raise and catch several exceptions during
>   its execution), where each report looks something like this:
>
> *** Exception raised (reporting due to +RTS -xc), stack trace:   GHC.List.CAF   --> evaluated by: Main.polynomial.table_search,
>   called from Main.polynomial.theta_index,   called from
>   Main.polynomial,   called from Main.zonal_pressure,   called from
>   Main.make_pressure.p,   called from Main.make_pressure,   called from
>   Main.compute_initial_state.p,   called from
>   Main.compute_initial_state,   called from Main.CAF   ...

Comment: I had no idea you could actually get a stack trace. Pity you need to recompile the entire Haskell Platform for profiling, but hey...

Comment: Thankfully I've had enough past troubles with profiling that I already had my entire sandbox compiled with profiling enabled...

Answer (score 7):

If you use `-Wall` in the ghc-options of your cabal file it'll give a warning of incomplete records.

```
module Foo where
data Bar = Bar { bar :: String, baz :: String }
f = Bar { baz = "foo" }

Foo.hs:5:5: Warning:
  Fields of ‘Bar’ not initialised: bar
  In the expression: Bar {baz = "foo"}
  In an equation for ‘f’: f = Bar {baz = "foo"}
Ok, modules loaded: Foo.
```